# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in assembly function

Tags: objective-c, assembly

I am trying to write a function in assembly that is callable from Objective-C code. I've gotten simple results by setting `%rax` and returning directly, but when I try to use the stack to store local variables, I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. Could someone take a look at this and tell me what's going wrong? My assembly looks like this:

```
.global _fn
_fn:
pushq %rbp
movq %rsp, %rbp
subq 0x8, %rsp
addq 0x8, %rsp
popq %rbp
ret
```

Xcode dumps this and indicates the crash is at `sub 0x8,%rsp` when I call `fn` from `main`:

```
0x0000000100020000  <+0000>  push   %rbp
0x0000000100020001  <+0001>  mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x0000000100020004  <+0004>  sub    0x8,%rsp
0x000000010002000c  <+0012>  add    0x8,%rsp
0x0000000100020014  <+0020>  pop    %rbp
0x0000000100020015  <+0021>  retq
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mere subtraction of 8 from `rsp` should not cause an exception.

Most likely you need to prefix the constants with the dollar sign. If you don't, (g)as will treat those numbers as memory operands at the corresponding addresses.

And accessing memory at address 8 is usually as good on the x86 platform as a NULL pointer dereference.

Comment: This is almost certainly the answer. If you run the code, notice that the address that `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is complaining about is 0x00000008.

Comment: +1 The Mach-O loader forces the bottom page of virtual memory to be inaccessible to user code.  This is the mechanism used to trap null pointer accesses but will, of course, cause the same exception on all locations on the bottom page - of which address 0x00000008 is one.

Comment: Cheers, that's it exactly. I should've paid more attention to the small print.